# I lost over 1000 games in chess.com rapid?

Tags: online-chess, computer-chess

Why does this keep happening?
Because I win over 800 games.
I am making the same mistake?
[image]

Comment: It would be nice to include some games of yours so we can see what is going on.

Comment: Go to Analysis of a game, choose personal analysis and use Share option. It will create a png, choose email and send it to yourself. Copy paste the game that came to you here and let the rest on us.

Comment: Congratulations

Comment: This is answered here: [Is there a reason to lose 1,000 chess games](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/41543/26335) where OP included a game for review.

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing a few of your games, it seems like you are indeed making the same mistake many times. That mistake is losing your queen - and not even to a tactic. You're either not moving it when the opponent attacks it, or putting it somewhere that it can be taken.

Although you should be careful with all your pieces, the queen is an important piece and you should be particularly careful with it. I would suggest changing your opening style so you don't move it so soon. Standard advice is to develop your knights and bishops first. When you do move it, make sure to pay attention and not put it where it can be taken. And when your opponent moves a piece, make sure to pay attention to what that piece can do in its new location. If it's attacking your queen, you should probably do something about that!